# GUI for Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine

I would like to be able to connect to my Google Compute Engine instance with GUI. I found a couple tutorial on how to do it.

[tutorial_1](https://medium.com/google-cloud/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5)

[tutorial_2](https://medium.com/google-cloud/graphical-user-interface-gui-for-google-compute-engine-instance-78fccda09e5c)

Both of them reference creating network rule with the following menu steps: `Compute > Compute Engine > Network`
However, I do not see these menu items in my Google Compute Engine console. Were they renamed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, please try the following path

Menu>VPC network>Firewall rules